# placing y-label and y-axis at right side using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

```
library(ggplot2)
# Define the data
data <- data.frame(
  "Predictors" = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7"),
 "Importances" = c(0.007371975, 0.106796751, 0.233634795, 0.013773545, 0.008526435, 0.031571105, 0.050614501)
)


library(ggpubr)
ggbarplot(data, x = "Predictors", y = "Importances", color = "grey", fill = "grey",
          sort.val = "asc") + # Sort the value in increasing order
  rotate() +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right")
```

Before I used the function `scale_y_discrete`, the figure looked like [image]

To place the y-label and y-axis at right side, I used `scale_y_discrete`, then the figure looks very weird:
[image]

How to correct the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you use `rotate()` to switch x- and y-axis. So, your vertical axis is actually the x-axis and you must use `scale_x_discrete()`:

```
ggbarplot(data, x = "Predictors", y = "Importances", color = "grey", fill = "grey",
          sort.val = "asc") + # Sort the value in increasing order
  rotate() +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: @YujieLiu The proper way to say "Thank You" on StackOverflow is to upvote the answers that you found helpful. Also, you should accept the most useful answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting the Predictors column on the right side of the plot, give this a go:

```
ggbarplot(data, x = "Predictors", y = "Importances", color = "grey", 
    fill = "grey", sort.val = "asc") + # Sort the value in increasing order
  rotate() +
  scale_x_discrete(position='top') +
  scale_y_reverse()
```